# 2 UIBarButtonItem's using the same custom view only added once

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I want to add a thin line between items in my `UIToolBar` so I'm creating a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view like so:

```
UILabel *separatorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 44)];
separatorLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRGB:0xe5edec];
UIBarButtonItem *separator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:separatorLabel];
```

Then I add my separator to the items array:

```
[items addObjectsFromArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:someButton1, separator, somebutton2, separator, someButton3, nil]];
```

I thought this would add 2 separators to my toolbar but it only adds the one at the end. Why is this?

I can fix this by creating 2 duplicate labels and UIBarButtonItem's, but is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any given instance of `UIView` can only appear in once in the view hierarchy. If you think about the APIs defined on `UIView`, this is fairly obvious. For example, `UIView` has a `frame` property which defines it's location in the superview. The `frame` property wouldn't make sense if the viewed appeared in two places.

So you need multiple instances. You can streamline your code by defining a method that creates separators:

```
- (UILabel *)newSeparator
{
    UILabel *separatorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 44)];
    separatorLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRGB:0xe5edec];
    UIBarButtonItem *separator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:separatorLabel];
    return separator;
}
```

And then you can add your items like this:

```
[items addObjectsFromArray:@[button1, [self newSeparator], button2, [self newSeparator]];
```

Also, you don't need to use `UILabel` if you're only displaying a background color. You can just use `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you just created only one UIBarButtonItem object,so it showed one.
I think the better way is creating a UIBarButtonItem subclass with custom label,then create two objects of the subclass.
I hope my answer can help you.